# killed 9 while using python and opencv2 to read multiple video files into a list

Tags: python, opencv

The overall problem I'm trying to tackle is I want to find out if videoA is a subset of videoB. So if videoA is 2 seconds clip and videoB is 40s, do those two seconds occur in those 40s. To do this I'm reading video files with VideoCapture, and saving each frame of my video in a dictionary. But while reading videos I see this:

```
Videos/viper_SpineyBitterGoatOhMyDog.mp4
Videos/tsm_theoddone_CoyThirstyAlmondDoggo.mp4
Videos/wingsofdeath_HelplessOilyYogurtGOWSkull.mp4
Videos/rinnieriot_AbstruseEnjoyableOkapiCopyThis.mp4
Videos/imls_UnusualHelplessDogFloof.mp4
Videos/4.mp4
Videos/solorenektononly_LaconicFamousEggplantTwitchRaid.mp4
Videos/gripex90_CheerfulNeighborlyJayTheThing.mp4
Videos/tarzaned_GrossFlirtyMooseFutureMan.mp4
Videos/imaqtpie_LightPleasantPhoneSquadGoals.mp4
Killed: 9


    from moviepy.editor import *
    import imageio
    import json
    from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
    import random
    import cv2
    import os
    import threading
    from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
    import argparse
    import imutils

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    videoPaths = self.getListOfDownloadedVideos()

    videosByFrame = {}
    for path in videoPaths:
        print path
        images = []
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        success = True
        while success:
            #print "Before READ"
            success,image = vidcap.read()
            #print "After READ"
            images.append(image)
        videosByFrame[path] = images
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        vidcap.release()
```

Is there something in vidcap.read() that would cause it to kill my python script?

Comment: Running out of memory.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Is there a way in python to check how much memory is left?

Comment: you probably cannot keep ALL frames from ALL videos uncompressed in memory (bad plan !)